# An Axiomatic Treatment of Mathematics from First Principles to the Major Subjects?

Tags: reference-request, logic, axioms

I'm looking for a book - more likely, books - that could take me from the axioms of mathematical logic up to the major subjects of mathematics, like analysis, algebra, geometry, etc.

For example, a book that starts from first principles in propositional calculus... a book that takes the logic proved therein as axioms to do set theory. And then a book that takes set theory and uses it to construct the real numbers. From there, a book to prove the real number properties and basic analysis. This last book could probably be some combination of Rudin and Spivak. (I'm not really sure where geometry fits in with this - as I haven't had any geometry at the college level yet, other than topology.)

So who has the best list?

The reason I ask is that I'm making a sort of outline of mathematics for myself to study from, and I want it to be as rigorous as possible, which means I want to cite specific theorems and definitions and axioms in all my proofs. This may seem over the top to some, but I'm a bit obsessive about everything being super-logical, and perhaps I can publish some kind of axiomatic book(s) one day if it doesn't already exist.

EDIT: I've decided on a few books that I'm going to try to use.

[*Mathematical Logic* by George Tourlakis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470280743)

[The Bourbaki *Theory of Sets*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540225250)

and

[Jech's *Set Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540440852)

I'd still love to hear the opinions of real mathematicians and/or more experienced students who might have some insight here. Until that happens, I will be journeying through the above books.

Comment: This is not a good way to study mathematics. But I think the Bourbaki books are supposed to do this.

Comment: Yuan's comment above implies a certain universality about his statement. It might not be a good way for him to study mathematics, nor for most people, but it could be for some. In retrospective I wish I had been taught the way the OP wants to learn. So many things confused me that only got answers after three yers of studying... @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @Git: It can be overdone. e.g. if you went so far as to try and make a library of formal proofs that could be mechanically verified, then I vaguely recall people estimating it would take years (decades?) of person effort even for an elementary subject.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't doubt that that is right, but it does't have to be like that. The OP is only asking to start from the most elementary stuff and go up, not that everything has to be proved formally.

Comment: @Git @ Hurkyl You are both correct. There are technically an unlimited number of results that one could catalog, but I'm only seeking to catalog important results upon which more advanced theorems depend. And I'm also not trying to do it all formally. The idea would be that you "prove" the informal language using the formal language, and then after mentioning this proof once or twice, never explicitly refer to the formal language in the proofs. I hope that made sense - I realize I'm wording it vaguely.

Comment: @Qiaochu Thanks for the tip! I forgot about the Bourbaki books. Perhaps they are a little outdated now, but definitely a good place to start! And I know that this may appear a strange way to learn. All the more power to you if you don't have the curse I have of needing to do it from the ground up. It's not that I don't trust that the results of those who came before us are correct - it just helps me to organize the information in my brain if I have it all written down sequentially.

Comment: @Qiaochu I should also add that I agree this is not the way to learn math if you're learning things like algebra and analysis for the first time. At least for me. I'm not a "new math" advocate, as it were.

Comment: I don't know of any books on propositional calculus that aim to achieve your goal. However when you start doing real numbers, I can recommend the books Analysis I and Analysis II by Terence Tao. Analysis I starts by defining the piano axioms and then constructs the natural numbers from this. Then the integers are constructed, and after this the rational numbers and then finally the real numbers are constructed. The author spends about 5 or 6 chapters on this, and then he starts doing calculus with focus on the theorems rather than computations. The second book studies real analysis.

Comment: Well, open up Russell and Whitehead's _Principia Mathematica_, and when you finally prove ([*110.643, in volume II](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2010/11/principia_83_lg2.jpg)) that $1 +_c 1 = 2$ (that's cardinal sum) you might wish you hadn't.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks - Tao's books sound like just what I was looking for.

@ Arthur You have a good point there. I'm not really doing a rigorous symbolic development though, so luckily I won't have anything like that. I'm still using words and everything - just looking for a basic sort of foundation.

Comment: FYI, there are several projects to produce, order and store "all" mathematics formally, specifically in the computer community. The [Mizar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_system) seems to be the largest one, though there are more active ones. [Here](http://markun.cs.shinshu-u.ac.jp/mirror/mizar/JFM/) is the full (not completely ordered) list of their theorems, they are available in pfd and in code format. All the Proofs are downloadable from their page as well. Predicate logic is presumed. Obviously, it's all written to be formalized and the text has no dedactic motivation.

Comment: Which axioms of mathematical logic?  There exist several sets of axioms in two-valued propositional calculus (and often, if not always, for other propositional calculi also).  The set of proven theorems has no termination point.  Predicate calculus also has different axiom sets and has no termination point for its theorems also.  Even though in principle different axiom sets come as equivalent, since deductions happen in the real world, I don't see how you will *necessarily see* the same set of mathematical theorems, since you've seen different theorems when developing the foundations.

Comment: The main issue with this approach is the material learned earlier won't help later. It's like an engineer first learning quantum physics, then molecular chemistry, etc., before finally learning how to design a bridge. By the time you get to bridge design, the material you learned about quantum physics isn't particularly useful. Similarly, if you want to learn how to solve a PDE with Fourier series, knowing how to construct the reals from the naturals isn't directly relevant. There's nothing wrong with learning logic - it's my own field - but in many cases the *mathematics* doesn't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience, an historical approach can be useful.

Why not try with :

> Morris Kline, [Mathematics: The Loss of Certainty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195030850), Oxford University Press, 1980 .

It explains the road to modern math, including the big isue regarding Foundations of Math (and the birth of Mathematical Logic).

For an understanding of Math Log and Set Theory, I would suggest you the 2 volumes set :

> George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521168465), Cambridge UP, 2010.